# spark query: unclosed character literal

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hiveql

Im executing this query with spark using HiveQL:

```
var hiveContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)

result = hiveContext.sql("select linestatus, sum(quantity) as sum_qty,count(*) as count_order from lineitem
where shipdate <= '1990-09-16' group by linestatus order by
linestatus")
```

But Im getting this error:

```
<console>:1: error: unclosed character literal
       where shipdate <= '1990-09-16' group by linestatus order by
```

Do you know understand why?

Comment: Try double quotes instead of single quotes? i.e ... where shipdate <= "1990-09-16" ...

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I already try that and also didnt work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Multiline strings in Scala have to be enclosed using triple quotes:

```
hiveContext.sql("""
    select linestatus, sum(quantity) as sum_qty,count(*) as count_order 
    from lineitem
    where shipdate <= '1990-09-16' group by linestatus order by linestatus""")
```